# How do you add two arrays together visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I know this is a stupid question, but I've spent 4 days trying to figure it out. I am trying to add two arrays each with 10 different elements together, not as a sum, but as an example this is just for three though, [1,3,5] + [4,7,9} = [4,10,14]. I have the two arrays displayed in labels for the first two buttons and another label for the "sum". I am just lost on how to add them up. Heres my code.

```
Public Class Form1
        Dim array1() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
        Dim array2() As Integer = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
        Dim array3() As Integer = {3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21}
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Button1.Click
        For i = 0 To array1.Length - 1
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text & "," & array1(i)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Button2.Click
        For i = 0 To array2.Length - 1
            Label2.Text = Label2.Text & "," & array2(i)
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
    Button3.Click
   End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying add 2 numbers together in the same position in two arrays, that's pretty easy.

from the button event you would send the arrays.

Button.click event

```
      Dim list1 As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
        Dim list2 As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
        Dim Results = Add_Groups(list1.ToArray, list2.ToArray)
```

```
Private Function Add_Groups(array1() As Integer, array2() As Integer) As String
        'Make sure each group has the same number of elements
        If array1.Length <> array1.Length Then Return "Groups aren't equal"

 'Set returnvalue
        Dim RV As String = ""

        'Iterate through each group and add them together and add them to the returnvalue
        For I As Integer = 0 To array1.Length - 1

     'Add location I from group1 and group 2
            Dim Sum = array1(I) + array2(I)

            'Add to returnvalue
            If RV.Length = 0 Then
                RV += Sum.ToString
            Else
                RV += "," + Sum.ToString
            End If

            'last five lines could be replaced with
            '     RV += If(RV.Length = 0, "", ",") + Sum.ToString
        Next
        'Add brackets
        RV = "[" + RV + "]"
        Return RV
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1) function:

```
Dim array1() As Integer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
Dim array2() As Integer = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
Dim array3() As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = String.Join(", ", array1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Label2.Text = String.Join(", ", array2)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    array3 = array1.Zip(array2, Function(x, y) x + y).ToArray
    Label3.Text = String.Join(", ", array3)
End Sub
```

If you don't want to use LINQ, then:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If array1.Length = array2.Length Then
        ReDim array3(array1.Length - 1)
        For i As Integer = 0 To array1.Length - 1
            array3(i) = array1(i) + array2(i)
        Next
        Label3.Text = String.Join(", ", array3)
    End If
End Sub
```